# How do you prioritise which part of the window gets closed first when the window is shrunk in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this window which is full of little user controls and each of those user controls has a 3 row grid. Now when I shrink the window the content in the rows gets cut (vertically). But content in row 1 is the most important bit, content of row 0 is slightly less important and the content of row 2 is the least important, so I would like to make it so, that when shrunk, row 2 disappears first, then row 0.
Any suggestions?

Edit: here is the xaml of my little user control:

```
 <Grid x:Name="suzi">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="Azure" Background="Black" Content="D00" FontSize="15" Name="LabelShow">
        <Label.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Ime naprave</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="FullName"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Label.ToolTip>
    </Label>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbSV" Grid.Row="2" Background="Black" IsHitTestVisible="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=Slider, Path=Value, StringFormat=0}" Foreground="Azure" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15" BorderBrush="Black"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,1.846"/>
    <Rectangle  x:Name="af1" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
        Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="center"  Grid.RowSpan="3" StrokeThickness="1" />

    <Slider Style="{StaticResource StyleForSlider}" Name="Slider" Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="1" TickFrequency="100" Maximum="100" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" />

</Grid>
```

Edit2: so far I'm trying:

```
  private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {           
        double neki = suzi.ActualHeight;
        if (neki <= 75)
        {
            LabelShow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            tbSV.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            LabelShow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            tbSV.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

But It just doesn't work right as I would need the slider row to expand over the hidden ones... (and here I'm hidding items one at a time not entire rows, but this is the closest I got to it so far...)

Answer (score 0):

You can give each row a minimum dimensions which might be enough for you:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="10"/>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I've not seen anything to alter how the default behaviour works, it follows the usual top-left to bottom-right type order.

Comment: I tried this option but it doesn't change anything for me, the elements still get cut, I am trying to make them disappear (as in visibility->Hidden) when they they would normally get cut.